# How can I get IP/host using windows commandline?

Tags: windows, command-line, dns

```
nslookup something.com 127.0.0.1

nslookup 10.20.30.40 127.0.0.1
```

Will send a query to 127.0.0.1 UDP 53.

**I want to use "127.0.0.1:545/UDP"** as a DNS resolver.

Is there any good commandline tool(Open source & free only) that I can
call it from command line?

Something like this:

https://github.com/jedisct1/dnscrypt-proxy/tree/master/src/hostip

Sadly, it can't resolve IP to hostname, so I don't use it.

hostip.exe -r 127.0.0.1:545 something.com

Comment: Also what version of Windows?

Answer (score 2):

Well, documentation seems a bit inconsistent.

According to [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490737.aspx) (via "[nslookup specify server port](https://www.google.com/search?q=nslookup%20specify%20server%20port)"):

In the nslookup console you can just type:

```
set port=545
```

To set the server port. In theory that means on the command line you can do:

```
nslookup -port=545 something.com 127.0.0.1
```

However I tried this on Windows 7 and it had no effect. Interestingly, the in-console help does not show `port` as a valid option on my system, yet clearly it *knows* about the option because `set po=123` sets `port` (according to `set all`). So I can't really explain how it knows to expand po to port but does not list port as an option and does not honor it.

There is a [second nslookup doc](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725991.aspx) that states something different, though. For whatever reason Windows 7 is conspicuously skipped in the "applies to" list so I can't test it, but that says you can do the following for other versions of Windows:

```
nslookup /set port=545 something.com 127.0.0.1
```

My version of nslookup does not have a /set option, though.

In any case type `nslookup /?` and see what your options are.

Comment: `nslookup "-set port=545" something.com 127.0.0.1` seemed to do the trick for me on Windows 7.

Comment: `nslookup "-set port=545"` will NOT actually use port 545 if you check your logs or use a packet analyzer like Wireshark. At least not on Windows 7.